# Form does not submit if action present

Tags: html, forms, apache, wamp

A few days ago I set up a small development server. Running on Windows Vista Business and the latest WAMP.

Today I wrote a simple script to test something, and when I hit the submit button, nothing happens. It doesn't submit to the same page, it doesn't give me a 404 not found (which it should). Nothing. The page doesn't even flicker:

```
<form method='POST' action='controller.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='test' value='test' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Nothing! However, if I remove the action, as follows, the page submits to itself and a probe of the global $_POST variable shows the hidden value is passed.

```
<form method='POST'>
```

Even the following works:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
```

Is there something I've missed in the apache setup??

Comment: Anything in the status bar?  And what happens if you give the form a name?

Comment: Is `controller.php` available when you call it via browser?

Comment: If the submit button has a name and value, does that make a difference?

Comment: Just tested this code on my end and got the 404 error.  Is this exactly what you put in your code?  Try double checking for spelling errors.

Comment: Checked and double checked. Nothing happens. The page does not redirect, reload, nothing. It's as if the 'submit' is set as a 'button'.

Comment: The name-attribute is missing in the form-tag. This may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Through much trial and error I got to a point where it only happened in Chrome. Turned out to be a malformed 'base' tag in the . This didn't affect any other browser!

Thanks for everyone's input.